# How to clear logfile everyday in python?

Tags: python-3.x, logfile, python-logging

I develop a python desktop application and I have log in the application, so I use the logging module. I would like to clear that log file in every morning.

Does anyone know, how to clear those files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimedRotatingFileHandler module for logging.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# CONFIGURATION TO ROTATE LOGS EVERYDAY
rotate = TimedRotatingFileHandler('sample.log', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
logger.addHandler(rotate)
formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
rotate.setFormatter(formater)
```

you can refer more here: [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler)